# Is there a mechanism to disable insert into table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is exists purely to serve as an array for some logic.

The table should have only one row otherwise my logic fails.
Is there any DDL command to disable insert into table?

As of now - I have inserted that 'one row' of data that is required for my logic, and now, plan to create an after insert trigger to delete the newly entered record. B)

However I noticed that there were some ALTER TABLE commands to disable/ enable keys, so I was wondering if there is an alternative to the trigger code.

```
mysql> select version();
5.6.25-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log
```

Answer (score 3):

This is generally not how we're supposed to use relations, but it can be done with a column that may take on only one value, but which also has a `UNIQUE KEY` over it:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
   `ActualData1` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `ActualData2` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `ActualData3` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

   `Dummy` ENUM("!") NOT NULL DEFAULT "!",
   UNIQUE KEY `OnlyOneRowAllowed` (`Dummy`)
);
```

…if you don't mind there being an additional column present that you're otherwise never going to use.

Comment: It can insert with `INSERT INTO MyTable (ActualData1, Dummy) VALUES (0,0)`

Comment: I see , I missed the part that you have used `default "!"` for `dummy` field. My Bad.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, don't grant the `INSERT` privilege on this table to regular users.